# Single Column layout

Tags: two-column

I'm writing a technical report as part of my studies, but, I'm learning how to use LaTeX. I have a skeleton structure based approach that requires makefiles.

I cannot seem to figure out how I would have a single column, instead of a two-column page I normally work in (when writing papers) - This is just a technical report so needs one column (Just like I would find in office packages).

I have tried using the following:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper,landscape, onecolumn, 10pt]{article}
```

What am I doing wrong? P.S. I'm very new to LaTeX.

Comment: Simply `\documentclass{article}` will give you a one-column layout. Please add a minimal working example of your document.

Comment: @JosephWright SO shall I remove `\LoadClass` instead?

Comment: @user1326876: `\LoadClass` is for writing “new” classes that build on existing ones; it's not intended for the ’user’ — the user is expected to use `\documentclass`, as joseph says

Comment: Did replacing `\LoadClass` solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,10pt]{article}
```

at the beginning of your `.tex` file.
The command `\LoadClass` is used when writing `.cls` files, which is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

For those using packages which default to two columns (such as `apa7`), add the `doc` argument to the `documentclass` command.

For example: `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, doc]{apa7}`

This will create a document with a single column.